# How to store additional user in Identity claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity

User 1.* Wallet

Should I store all user's Wallet in identity claim? so I don't have to keep making round trips to the database to retrieve the user's wallet all the time?

Store like this -

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myWallet.Wallet.Name))
          claims.Add(new Claim("wallet_name[0]", myWallet.Wallet.Name));
```

Get like this -

```
        Name = claims.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "wallet_name[0]")?.Value ?? "
```

Too many wallets is bad?

Comment: Why are you using `new Claim("wallet_name[0]", myWallet.Wallet.Name)` instead of `new Claim("Wallet", myWallet.Wallet.Name)` ?

Comment: What would happen if there are multiple wallets? Claim("Wallet", myWallet.Wallet.Name) <-- keep adding to this? also need to add other details such as wallet_type, wallet_reference etc

Comment: If there are multiple claims of same type, you need to iterate over them.
As for adding other details, it seem to be more logical to have a table (or whatever DB equivalent you're using) to store wallet data, the user claim would contain wallet id.

Comment: The problem is, the wallet information such as name would need to be displayed in the drop-down menu of the user's control panel. What to do there?

Comment: Instead of using claims, create a table for wallets and have each wallet reference its owner, then you can simply query DB for current user wallets.

Comment: It's already like that! but need to store it somewhere in cache? so that the app don't need to make a query to the database over and over again!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think user claims are also stored in DB and queried from it.
If you're using EF, you can use a singleton and let it handle the caching, but you'll need to make sure you call SaveChanges on every change.